# Cockroaches in a speaker cabinet

Tags: home, pest-control

I bought a pair of speakers on Craigslist that turned out to have little roaches living inside. Fortunately, I noticed them before any escaped into my apartment, so I took the speakers back to the trunk of my car immediately. Then I sprayed raid all over the inside of my trunk and a liberal amount inside the speaker cabinet.

I've looked inside the trunk a couple times over the last 2 days and haven't seen any live roaches inside the cabinets or elsewhere. But before I take them back inside, I need to *know* that the roaches are all dead and that there are no eggs inside that can hatch. So how can you be sure?

Comment: Just burn the damn thing! :)

Comment: But they're Polk Monitor 5's! I can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't totally confirm the non-existence of eggs without visually inspecting every part of the cabinets.

While some recommend using an IGR (insect growth regulator) the simplest thing you can do it wait it out. According to [this source](http://www.orkin.com/cockroaches/cockroach-eggs/), the eggs hatch in 24 to 38 days, reaching adulthood by 103 days on average. If you don't mind waiting a few months you will know for sure. Otherwise (if if more begin to appear), pursue the chemical route.

Answer (score 3):

Rubbing alcohol (isopropyl) in a spray bottle will kill roaches, spiders, etc., then it evaporates leaving no smell or residual poison. You would have to open the speakers and spray any bugs or eggs, but it would beat smelling bug spray! Probably don't want to spray the speaker material or foam.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a freezer (or can use someone else's) large enough to contain at least one speaker then you can put the speaker(s) in the freezer for a few days. This [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi2-9KM7PfSAhWLllQKHUMPCrsQFggyMAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.extension.umn.edu%2Fgarden%2Finsects%2Ffind%2Fcockroaches%2F&usg=AFQjCNHkgZhJCYtzmvb5V9ydjLd4w6w9Cg&sig2=d-bYypyE0uJadj-sM8L6BA) says zero degrees F for 5 days.